# How to get trackpad / mouse wheel scrolling events in MacOS Catalyst app?

Tags: ios, macos, mac-catalyst

We built our iPad app for MacOS using Catalyst and I cannot figure out how to get two-finger trackpad scrolling gestures to work in a custom UIView. The standard UIKit components (e.g., UITableView) scroll with the standard two-finger trackpad scrolling gestures. But how do you handle them in a custom UIView?

The custom UIViewViewController adds a typical UIPanGestureRecognizer which invokes the gesture handler method when the trackpad is pressed and I move my finger. But it doesn't invoke the handler with just two fingers brushing the trackpad.

Comment: Similar to another Catalyst omission, being able to detect Magic Mouse pan gestures.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this now in iOS 13.4 using this code:

```
panGesture.allowedScrollTypesMask = UIScrollTypeMask.continuous
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/3538978-allowedscrolltypesmask

Comment: Anything similar that can be added to a UIScrollView?

Comment: @RanLearns, I thought that UIScrollView got this behavior for free. I haven't played around with it to find out though.

Comment: Looks like the same thing is not available for pinch.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed by Apple DTS that this is not currently possible.

> We have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no
>   supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently
>   shipping system configurations.

(Feb 2020)

Answer (score 0):

If you can put your UIView into a `UIScrollView`, you can then use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to detect scrolling. However, you will then need to immediately undo any scrolling movements in `scrollViewDidScroll` if you don't actually want the view to move.